# what is the meaning of execution time of a query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I want to know about what is actually meant by the execution time of a query in MYSQL. And how to reduce the execution time using indexing techniques?

Comment: Seems you didn't do any kind of research before asking here

Comment: i have done. but they didn't answer my question properly.

Comment: " And how to reduce the execution time using indexing techniques?" indexing won't always help to gain more performance... MySQL's optimizer is cost based and can choose a full table scan over index access when alot of records are selected from a table.

Comment: If you use innodb you can configure the innodb buffer pool so MySQL runs more like a in memory database when the buffers are full..

Answer (score 1):

"Execution time" is simply a stopwatch.  That is, looking at a clock on the wall.  It is a reasonable metric for (1) stressing impatience of user waiting for data, and (2) burden on the server.

There are hundreds of web pages going into details about indexing.  And probably there are books written on the subject.  This forum can help you with *one* query at a time.

I'll plug [*my index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) which is a distillation of tips for the thousands of questions I have answered about indexing.

Answer (score 0):

> Execution time depend on many factor like **wait statistics, I/O, compiles, recompiles, network time, etc**. 
>   where as,
>   Indexing is a way to optimize performance of a database by minimizing the number of disk accesses required when a query is processed.
>   An index or database index is a data structure which is used to quickly locate and access the data in a database table.
>   So, Basically both are two different things and you can not combine both one thing
>   I have some useful link which can give you better clearity on this topic please look once at when you have lot of time with peace mind-

https://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-an-index/

https://dzone.com/articles/measuring-query-execution-time-what-is-most-accura

Comment: You link to sources which are not MySQL

Comment: I think Index concept / execution concept are almost same for any database lke MYSQL, ORACLE,Postgresql etc. As above asked concept are basic which are included in every DB

Comment: Besides the index in the https://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-an-index/ is explained wrong.. The optimizer in anny database system will calculate if a index should be used or not.. Making a index wlll not force SQL into actually using it if a FULL table scan is cheaper..

Comment: besides " Indexing is a way to optimize performance of a database by minimizing the number of disk accesses ... when a query is processed." in MySQL every row that uses a B-tree index requires one or more random (disk|memory) I/O operations to [lookup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/estimating-performance.html)..  Like i said the Optimizer is cost based if you select 60% from a table for example MySQL  like most likely choose a FULL table scan because 1 random disk I/O is required instead of multiple random (disk/memory) I/O for every record that matches.